# Fading Image Gallery

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

The image gallery i have and having issues with seems to create some kind of space to the right when a viewer is smaller then say 350px leaving a gap to the entire right side of my website. I am trying to make this image gallery responsive so that every thing resizes based on the viewer size.

Here is the code:

**CSS**

```
.crossfade > figure {
    animation: imageAnimation 30s linear infinite 0s;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    color: transparent;
    height: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: -1px;
    z-index: 0;
    border: thin solid black;
}

.crossfade > figure:nth-child(1) {
  background-image:url(001.jpg);
}
.crossfade > figure:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
  background-image:url(002.jpg);
}
.crossfade > figure:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 12s;
  background-image:url(003.jpg);
}
.crossfade > figure:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 18s;
  background-image:url(004.jpg);
}
.crossfade > figure:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 24s;
  background-image: url(005.jpg);
}

@keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  8% {
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
<figure class="crossfade">
    <figure></figure>
    <figure></figure>
    <figure></figure>
    <figure></figure>
    <figure></figure>
  </figure>
</body>
```

Hope this gives a very good idea of what I'm working with that you maybe able to replicate any issues. I feel there is something that can be done with this image gallery that would make it good for a responsive website but something isn't right causing a shift to the right.

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: Like i said when i put this code in to my site it seems to react oddly creating roughly a 100px gap on the right side of the website. If i take out this code it looks fine. With the Image Gallery it goes hay wire :(

Comment: You have to show more code. I tested your code and I don't see any gap.

Comment: Please check www.basqueinternationalspice.com as reference to my issue. This is what i have been working on.

Answer (score 0):

First up, your `<figure>` tags have margins. Is it necessary?

If not, add this to your `figure` css:
`margin: 0px;`

Second, do you mean this gap?

[image: Is this your gap?]

If so, your title is overflowing over here.
[image]

To fix it, reduce your `font-size` or use javascript to resize your font according to your page width.

**EDIT:** You might want to add this to your `<head>` tag:
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no,minimal-ui">`

Fixes scaling issues on mobile browsers, but make sure your font is big enough because it disables zooming.

*Sorry if I'm a little off topic. I just wanna perfect whatever I work on.*

Comment: That is the gap i was referring to. I will check the page Title, and also the the <figure> tag to see if these are issues. I feel convinced it is the image gallery but these seem like possibilities as well, Thank you. I will comment again on any findings.

Comment: @Warlo What's up? Did it fix the problem?

Comment: @Warlo One more suggestion. If you want a quick and dirty fix, you can go `overflow-x: hidden;` in your css for the `<body>` tag.